# Not enough input arguments while solving ODE in matlab

Tags: matlab, ode45

I am trying to solve 3 ODE's that are actually rate equations.This is how i intend to represent the equations and furthur solve them using ODE45 in MATLAB.

```
    function dy=rate1(t,y)
    dy=zeros(3,1);
    k1=1;
    k2=2;
    dy(1)=-k1*y(1);
    dy(2)=k1*y(1)-k2*y(2);
    dy(3)=k2*y(2);
    [t,x]=ode45(@rate1,[0,12],[5,0,0]);
    plot(t,x);
```

But i keep getting the error "Not enough input arguments." I am new to MATLAB. Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please add context: how are you passing this function to ode45? Where is the error coming from? You're not just pressing the "run" button in the matlab editor, are you?

Comment: How are you calling `ode45`?  That code is missing.

Comment: I have added the furthur code. Still getting the same error.

Comment: If you're really trying to call the function from itself, as in your example, then you should first get familiar with MATLAB. Take a look at the "Getting started" part of the documentation, it's really helpful. I'm also suspecting that you're trying to *run* the function rather than calling it.

Comment: The call to `ode45` has to be **separate** from the ODE you are trying to solve.  You're placing them in one function.  I've marked a duplicate so you can see how to properly use it.